# Find a subgroup of $F$ to which $F/K$ is isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $F$ be the multiplicative group of all functions mapping $\mathbb{R}$ into $\mathbb{R}$, that do not assume the value $0$ at any point of $\mathbb{R}$. Now let $K$ be the subgroup of $F$ consisting of the nonzero constant functions.

> How can I find a subgroup of $F$ to which $F/K$ is isomorphic?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: If $f \in F$, the ratio $\bar{f}(x) = f(x)/f(0)$ is unchanged when $f$ is multiplied by a constant, and $\bar{f}$ uniquely determines $f$ modulo $K$.